# Script Add 2 blank rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you help me please?

I want a script to add 2 blank rows after a name change.

Something like this:

```
COLUMN A           - COLUMN B    - COLUMN C - COLUMN D - COLUMN E
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
bb                 - bb          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
bb                 - bb          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
```

i want this:

```
COLUMN A           - COLUMN B - COLUMN C - COLUMN D - COLUMN E
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
blank                            **- 15€      - 15€      - 15€**
blank                            blank      blank      blank  
bb                 - bb  
bb                 - bb
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

The following script will iterate through `data` which is column A and it will insert two rows in between the cells their values are different.

---

### Solution:

```
function addrows() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const data=sh.getRange('A1:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  let c=0; 
  data.forEach( (row,index) => {
     let temp = row;
     if (index>0 && temp!=data[index-1]){
       sh.insertRowsAfter(index+c, 2);
       c+=2;
     }                     
  });
}
```

---

### Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your help. :D
Just one last thing.. when i add the 2 blank rows, on last columns i have to make a sum, how can i do that with a script? Thanks

Comment: @Nuno which sum exactly? Please edit your question to clarify what you want. Keep in mind that separate questions should be asked in separate posts.

Comment: i already edit the post. Thanks. :)